# Using variable with delay in WhenEvents in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, eventhandler

I have a system of differential equations which is solved correctly. However, I want to trigger two events, one of which depends on the "time elapsed" after of the first event trigger. Is it possible to ever satisfy the second WhenEvent function:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. NDSolve[{
  y'[t] == n[t]*b - a y[t],
  y[0] == 0,
  n[0] == 1,
  WhenEvent[y[t] > y0, {n[t] -> 0, timeEvent1 = t}],
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, timeEvent1 + delay] == 0 && y[t] < y0, n[t] -> 1]},
 y, {t, 0, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {n[t] \[Element] {0, 1}}, 
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]],
{t, 0, 100}],
{b, .2, 2}, {a, .1, 2}, {delay, 1, 10}, {y0, 1.5, 20}]
```

where n[t] is a DiscreteVariable. In my system, when n[t]->0, y[t] begins to decrease. What I would like to happen can be summarized in the below pseudo-code:

```
when y[t] reaches a certain level, y[t] begin to decay,
once y[t] decays after a given time elapse of "delay", if y[t] falls below the
above mentioned level, it beings to be produced again.
Rinse and repeat.
```

I hope this was clear enough. I'm hoping to get oscillations like this:

[image: real]
[image: desired]

I think my issue is that the Mod[t,time+delay]==0 is never satisfied due to the nature of the variable t during the integration and n[t] never gets switched back to 1. Event 1 is triggered, but Event 2 is never triggered even though y[t] falls below yo and a time of time+delay has elapsed. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to declare `timeEvent` as a `DiscreteVariable`:

```
 Manipulate[
    Plot[Evaluate[
      y[t] /. (ff = 
         NDSolve[{y'[t] == n[t]*b - a y[t], y[0] == 0, n[0] == 1, 
           timeEvent1[0] == 0,
             WhenEvent[y[t] > y0, { n[t] -> 0, timeEvent1[t] -> t}],
              WhenEvent[t - timeEvent1[t] == delay, n[t] -> 1 ]}, 
                   y, {t, 0, 100}, 
                    DiscreteVariables -> {n[t] \[Element] {0, 1}, timeEvent1[t]}, 
                 MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]])], {t, 0, 100}], {b, .2, 2}, 
                    {a, .1,   2}, {delay, 1, 10}, {y0, 1.5, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer!